# Icon and Background color together

Tags: android, xml, background

I need to add both background and an icon and I ought to use background property for both in xml. I cannot set both at the same time so how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML for setting the background, and the property "**drawableRight**" or "**drawableLeft**" to set the Icon this is the way I do it.